# replace from 2 lines

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to replace the below text

```
<div>
    &nbsp;</div>
<div>
    &nbsp;</div>
```

to be

```
<div></div>
```

and I have used the below

```
update `mytable` set post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<div>\n' & CHAR(9) & '&nbsp;</div>\n<div>\n' & CHAR(9) & '&nbsp;</div>', '<div></div>')
```

and get below error

```
 #1292 - Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '<div> '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an ampersand.  That is the Bitwise AND operator (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) and it will return an unsigned integer.

Use concat() (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

```
update `mytable` 
set post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 
  concat('<div>\n\t','&nbsp;</div>\n<div>\n\t','&nbsp;</div>'),
  '<div></div>');
```

It will concatenate all of its arguments and takes the form:

```
concat(str1, str2, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the help, I still have something wrong, as no rows affected, and above code already taken from one of my records, I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @PeterElias, I updated my answer to change the char(9) to an escaped tab.  Try that.  If that doesn't work check your data to make sure you really have a new line followed by a tab.